# Displaying the time for the right time zone

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a .NET Core 2.2 web app running inside a `docker-compose` app. I'm saving different UTC time stamps to a database, like this:

```
//set asked state on question
Question questionInDb = c.Questions.Single(x => x.Id == id);
questionInDb.Asked = true;
questionInDb.AskTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
c.SaveChanges();
```

In the `apppsettings.json` I have a section for my app's settings, containing the locale the application is supposed to run on. I set the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` like so:

```
//get locale from settings, defaulting to de-DE
string locale = "de-DE";
locale = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:Locale");
var ci = new CultureInfo(locale, false);
//actually setting locale
 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

I set up my Entity Framework to set all `DateTime`s to `DateTimeKind.Utc`, so the app knows the `DateTime`s it gets are all UTC.

Now, when displaying the time on a view, it's not the right hour. In the `view.cshtml` I'm using `@q.AskTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yy")`, but it always returns the exact value from the database. It's supposed to show one hour more.

I even tried setting the container's timezone to CET (Centran Euopean Time) using `ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone` (in my `docker-compose` I set the environment variable `TZ` to `Europe/Berlin`).

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cultures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo) (also known as locales) are used for displaying and formatting data and is a different concept than timezones. You can find and create a specific [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo) from a timezone name and convert an UTC date and time using the `ConvertTimeFromUtc()` method.

Keep in mind that different operating systems use different timezone names. For example you can use `Europe/Berlin` for Linux and `Central Europe Standard Time` for Windows.

Example:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz;
try
{
    // Linux
    tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Berlin");
}
catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
{
    try
    {
        // Windows
        tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
    }
    catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
    {
        // Fallback to UTC
        tz = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
    }
}

var converted = tz.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Comment: thanks, this finally works! weirdly, my `TimeZoneInfo.Local` is GMT+1, which should be correct. How come the standard `DateTime.ToString()` doesn't take this into account?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. It seems to use the `TimeZoneInfo.Local` information for the method `DateTime.ToLocalTime()`. Now in my view I'm doing `@q.AskTime.ToLocalTime().ToString("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yy")` which works fine. First I was using your approach but I didn't want to have to iterate over each item to convert the time. This way seems more 'best practice' to me